# Получить доступ в верхнему элементу

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность получить элемент выше, зная только текст элемента ниже. Нужен селектор для элемента `class="hint-id" > span`

[image: пример]

Comment: Ну `document.querySelector('div.hint-id')`. В чём проблема?

Comment: Родитель доступен через parentNode, если речь о родителе. Если имеется в виду соседний элемент выше, имеющий того же родителя, что и известный элемент, можно использовать previousSibling.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно, обратимся к родительскому элементу и от него спустимся к нужному элементу.

```
document.querySelector('.hint-name').parentElement.querySelector('.hint-id').innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот селектор помог `//span[text()="test"]/preceding::span[1]`